# Аналог ZOC для ZSH + iTerm2

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, zsh

Есть замечательная софтина для macOS под названием ZOC Terminal - это удобный SSH клиент + терминал. Но к сожалению она платная и уступает бесплатным аналогам по многим вопросам. Недавно перешёл на iTerm2 + ZSH и возник вопрос: существует ли плагин для iTerm2 или ZSH, который позволял бы так же удобно хранить профили подключения к разным серверам, который бы не вынуждал вводить пароли, хост, порт, логины и т.д.? По некоторым причинам авторизовываться по ключу не всегда удобно.

Comment: Она не платная. Единственное неудобство с ней при неоплате - это то, что при старте программы надо нажать крестик один раз. Надо уточнить - я про ZOC 6 .

Answer (score 0):

можете воспользоваться [программой *sshpass*](https://gist.github.com/arunoda/7790979):

```
$ sshpass -p 'пароль' ssh опции-и-параметры-программы-ssh
```

чтобы не набирать эту команду повторно, можно либо воспользоваться историей команд, либо создать для неё псевдоним, добавив в конец rc-файла вашей оболочки (для *zsh* это `~/.zshrc`, для *bash* это `~/.bashrc` и т.д. и т.п.) строку:

```
alias server1="sshpass -p 'пароль' ssh опции-и-параметры-программы-ssh"
```

и запускать её, просто введя команду:

```
$ server1
```